# URL RewriteRule not working, Page not found!

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

Hello all i could use a little help i am using the latest version of Wampserver and i am having issues with RewriteCond... I have all the files/folders in the correct places but still it says Page not found!

Is the error in my code or in the Wampserver it's self? i have the rewrite_modual on

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule imgs/(.*)\.php /violation.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule page_files/(.*)\.php /violation.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule lang/(.*)\.php /violation.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule styles/(.*)\.php /violation.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule profile/(.*)\.php /violation.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example URL that is giving you the 404?

Comment: Oh yes sorry i was working lol, i'll copy past it. http://localhost/page_files/ shows this: Page not found
We're sorry but the requested URL was not found on this server.
This content may have moved, or is no longer available we apologize for the inconvenience. Only thing i can think of is something else is over-riding it? but how there is only one .httaccess

Answer (score 1):

It is your first rule: `RewriteRule ^.* - [L,QSA]`. It is matching all requests and causing the rest to be ignored.

**UPDATE**

To redirect `/page_files/` to the `violation.php`, add the following:

```
RewriteRule page_files/?$ /violation.php? [QSA,L]
```

If you wanted, it could be combined with your other `page_files` rule, but should work as-is.

This will catch all requests to the `page_files` path or anything within it

```
RewriteRule page_files/?(.*) /profile.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: i removed that line and i also cleaned it up to bear minimal to see if it works still nadda...^see above topic for new code

Comment: With your new rules, `http://localhost/page_files/` won't be redirected at all.  But, I do get `http://localhost/page_files/page.php` --> `http://localhost/violation.php`.

Comment: Well how do i make it so when the access the folder /page_files/ it sends them to my violation.php? it used to work on folders before all the updates i should have never altered the .httaccess file!!

Comment: Man it's still coming up as page not found, wtf is going on with my site lol, i am going to make a new project and test the code on just a couple simple pages and see what happens.

Comment: Nope @clmarquart even on a bear bones .html it still shows the folder.Index of /page_files. i wonder if its wampserver messing up ever since i updated it to the latest version its been acting really funny.

Comment: Do any rewrites work?  It could be that with your update, `mod_rewrite` is no longer enabled or that `AllowOverride none` is in place, not allowing our .htaccess file to work.

Comment: Yeah i am looking for it now, i decided to try to make a new folder called /test/ and when i added it to my .httaccess file it shows the directory "empty" of course but it still shows it which means its not working. i figured out why /page_files/ comes out as doc not found i forgot i added it to the protect list in smarty lol. //INITIATE SMARTY SECURITY
$folder = "base";
$secure_dirs[] = '../systemcore/';
$secure_dirs[] = '../core/functions/';
$secure_dirs[] = '../page_files/';
$secure_dirs[] = '../styles/';
$secure_dirs[] = '../imgs/';

$smarty->secure_dir = $secure_dirs;

Comment: I just opened the httpd.config file and it says # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
is that it?

Comment: There should be a section right after that for the `htdocs` folder, that looks very similar, but has `order allow,deny` and so on... Change the line there that says `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride all`

Comment: It should be similar to `<Directory C:/apache/htdocs> ... </Directory>`

Comment: Yeah i see it, it says #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    It says its on: >> AllowOverride all

Comment: Hard to tell from the comment....but it already is set to `AllowOverride all`?  Is that directory the one where your site is in?    Another way to tell if your `.htaccess` is not being used is to put some garbage in there and go to a page, it should give you an `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: lol i put: wamp server can suck my HD! 034034060360340634003460343460037@$#^#$^#$^#$^#$^46 no error message on page refresh so it's not being used...

Comment: Are there any other locations in any `.conf` file that is being used where there is a `AllowOverride none`?  If so, just change it to `AllowOverride all` to see if we can get this working...

Comment: i will have to check it i need to stop for a bit i will take a look and see it hope so its very annoying thanks for the help be back in a while.

Comment: Hey @clmarquar nope i looked all over its just not working! I created a new www/ and made a new index.html and a new .httaccess and added a password check in it for test/ folder and still nothing...

Comment: Ok i fixed it, after i uninstalled it i ran CCLeaner and Registry cleaner, then rebooted and Re-Installed it, i installed the older x2 version and it still did not work. Well after crying god why do you hate me i looked up to see my .htaccess had an error... O.o i had an extra t in it ".httaccess" lmao, its working again 100% lol, i was think it was the new wampserver "didn't like me" haha but oh well solved thanks for all the help you can slap me its been a long day! ^ hates vista, have be be very careful where i click moving files.

Comment: +1 for the enormous effort you've put it, and since Greg has not seen fit to reward you. :)